# Tile's gameobject is offset

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have made a basic scripted tile, it have set prefab as game object. Problem is, that gameobject is offset when door is placed. I would like to have gameobject on same location as tile.

[IMAGE: My problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOIPb.png)

---

**DoorTile.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;

public class DoorTile : TileBase
{

    public Sprite doorSprite;
    public GameObject doorObject;
    public Tile.ColliderType colliderType = Tile.ColliderType.Sprite;
    public override void RefreshTile(Vector3Int location, ITilemap tilemap)
    {
        tilemap.RefreshTile(location);
    }
    public override void GetTileData(Vector3Int location, ITilemap tilemap, ref TileData tileData)
    {
        tileData.gameObject = doorObject;
        tileData.colliderType = colliderType;
        tileData.sprite = doorSprite;
        tileData.flags = TileFlags.LockTransform;
        tileData.color = Color.white;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to your Tile Anchor being (0.5, 0.5, 0). You can modify your tile anchor under the Tilemap component to fix this, or you can simply add the offset to your Door object.

Comment: Thank you! GameObject offset can be set in Tile code? If so, is it set in GetTileData function?

Comment: The offset is for the entire Tilemap and can be set directly in the inspector @TomZMarsu

Comment: If you wish to offset your GameObject instead of the Tilemap, you would add the anchor to your GameObject's transform.position. it would be the tileAnchor on the Tilemap.